Problems with facet_* when nulls occur in multilayer rasters
When using tidyterra for multi-layer raster plotting, the facet_* function doesn't seem to work effectively when one of the layers has the null value “NA”. I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is a better solution?
library(terra)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyterra)

m <- matrix(c(1:24,NA), nrow=5, ncol=5)
n <- matrix(rep(5,time=25),nrow = 5,ncol = 5)

dt <- rast(c(A = rast(m),B = rast(n)))

ggplot()+
  geom_spatraster(data = dt,na.rm = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "transparent")+
  facet_grid(~lyr)+
  theme_bw()

! Plotting only layer "A" of class <integer>
Warning message:
Mixed layer classes found in `tidyterra::geom_spat*()`. 


Expected outcome：
data <- terra::as.data.frame(dt,xy=TRUE) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = c(A,B),names_to = 'layer', values_to = 'pre')
head(data)

ggplot(data = data,aes(x=x,y=y,fill = pre))+
  geom_tile(na.rm = TRUE)+
  scale_fill_viridis_c(na.value = "transparent")+
  facet_grid(~layer)+
  theme_bw()



The warning message says that the layers of dt do not all have the same data type. Indeed, one is an integer and one is a double:
is.int(dt)
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE

geom_spatraster doesn't know how to apply the same aesthetics to two different data types, so it only plots one. To fix this, we just need to make sure they are both doubles:
as_numeric_matrix <- function(x) matrix(as.numeric(x), ncol = ncol(x))

values(dt) <- as_numeric_matrix(values(dt))



you can do dt <- as.double(dt)

@RobertHijmans Thank you, I was hoping there was a simpler way.
